# Edit Jtable on double click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I need to edit table when user double clicks on row, with new values. I tried with `setValuesAt` method but it didn't do anything.

This is what I got so far but I don't know how to set new values to `Jtable`.

```
 public class Table extends JFrame {

        private JTable table;
        private JScrollPane jsPane;
        private DefaultTableModel model;
        private JPanel dialogPanel;
        private JTextField tf[];
        private JLabel lbl[];
        private JPanel panel;

        Object[] columns = new Object[]{"Name", "Last Name", "ID", "Email"};
        Object[][] inData ;

        public void prepareAndShowGUI() {

            setTitle("Overview");

            model = new DefaultTableModel() {

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);

            table = new JTable(model);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"a", "s", "w", "e"});
            }

            jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);

            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();
                        int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
                        int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(x, y));

                        String array[] = new String[table.getColumnCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            array[i] = (String) table.getValueAt(row, i);
                        }
                        populateTextField(array);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dialogPanel, "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        String[] values = new String[tf.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++) {
                            values[i] = tf[i].getText();

                        }
                        model.setValueAt(values, row, row);

                    }

                }
            });

            panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

            panel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panel.add(jsPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            getContentPane().add(panel);

            pack();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            prepareDialogPanel();

            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void prepareDialogPanel() {

            dialogPanel = new JPanel();
            int col = table.getColumnCount();
            dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(col, 1));
            tf = new JTextField[col];
            lbl = new JLabel[col];

            for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
                lbl[i] = new JLabel(table.getColumnName(i));
                tf[i] = new JTextField(10);

                dialogPanel.add(lbl[i]);
                dialogPanel.add(tf[i]);

            }
        }

        private void populateTextField(String[] s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                tf[i].setText(s[i]);

            }
        }

    }
 public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Table td = new Table();
                td.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you should make your model editable, so change this line:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

};
```

To:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return true; //use the row and col to determine which 
                    //cells are editable. If you want all, have this return true. 
    }

};
```

This will invoke the JTable's DefaultCellEditor, which will then call on the model's setValueAt method, when the user has made the change on the edit.

All of these components can be replaced with custom components to perform different actions.

Here's the official Oracle documentation on JTables:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

If you're trying to get your dialog to work, the problem is in these line:

```
String[] values = new String[tf.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++) {
    values[i] = tf[i].getText();
}
model.setValueAt(values, row, row);
```

Basically the setValueAt only works on a cell by cell basis. You can't update a whole row like this. Instead try:

```
for(int i=0;i<tf.length;i++)
{
   model.setValueAt(tf[i].getText(), row, i); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading his code wrong, but it looks like he doesn't really want to do this. Instead he wants a double click to open up a dialog window where the cell data is edited, and then the JTable's model is updated. Allowing for direct manipulation of the JTable cells would foul this. If I'm right, then your recommendation is not correct. Or maybe you are right, and his is an XY problem where is real best solution is to use a custom cell editor.... hard to say.

Comment: I read his question as how do you get it to edit it on a double-click. If the question gets changed to say that he wants a separate window to perform the edit, I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer to include the other case. It's currently waiting to be peer reviewed before it shows up.

Comment: Your own answer does not need a peer review to be updated by you (I believe). And regarding, `"I read his question as how do you get it to edit it on a double-click. If the question gets changed to say that he wants a separate window to perform the edit,"` -- it's what he's doing in his code. Just have a close look at his code and you'll see.

Comment: yes, sorry for been unclear. I need separate window for editing table.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought he was making the dialog because he didn't know about the built in editor. Now that I understand, I've updated my answer. Also when I initially went to edit my answer, it told me it had to be peer reviewed. When I updated it again, it took immediately, so I'm not sure what happened.